# How change selector for spoiler?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change a spoiler but i have problem with javascript code

This is the spoiler:
http://nathan3000.altervista.org/Jdownloader%20Spoiler/zzzz.html

1. When i click the image "MAC" the spoiler opens. When i click again MAC the spoiler closes. But when i click between the text the spoiler closes again. **I do not want the spoiler closes when I click in the middle of the text** *but only when i click image "MAC".* 
   **How can i do change selector so it only show/hides when i click the image?**
   I'm still clicking inside the `.OS container`
2. I don't understand why the table border doesn't appear on online version while on local version I can see the borders of tables.

The javascript code for spoiler is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); //href is needed for users without JS
 $('.OS').click(function(){
 if($(this).find(".details").is(":visible"))
 {
   $(this).find(".details").not(":hidden").hide("slow");
   return true;
 }
 else
 {

   $(this).find(".details").show("slow");
   return false;
 }
 });
 });  
 </script>     
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
.details {
display: none;
clear: both;
padding: 2px;
}
.nonjs{
    cursor:pointer;
}
img {
border: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is working:*

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".nonjs").removeAttr( "href"); 
    //href is needed for users without JS

     $('.OS').click(function(e){
               if(!$(e.target).parents('.details').length){
                            if($(this).find('.details').is(":visible"))
                            {
                                $(this).find('.details').not(":hidden").hide("slow");
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                $(this).find('.details').show("slow");
                                return false;
                            }
              }
    });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

put your spoiler/ popdown menu directly after your .OS image. right now your popdown is a child of the .OS container, so clicks on it are passed to the .OS click handler.

here is something like you want:

http://tempesthostingservices.com/t/zzzz.html

Comment: mmm..thanks, but in my version i can't see the content of spoiler. how can we fix it? Why the table border appears in local version but not on hoster?

Comment: simply remove the `style="display: block; "` from the .details div

Comment: as for the table styling on the hosted version, the over riding style seems to be coming from the `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="./JDownloader.org - Official Homepage_files/css(1).php">` in the head section. without seeing what you are seeing, it is hard to tell, but thats my quess

Comment: see the difference, please: http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4144/tableborder.png . This is your file downloaded on my pc, the borders appears on my local pc http://www.mediafire.com/?dng5gjapeao0kdw

Comment: yeah, same in mine. its something about the fact that the style sheet is being served as php, i think. try saving the style sheet, renaming it to with a .css expression and inlcudeing that version. it fixed the problem for me here: http://tempesthostingservices.com/t/zzzz.html

Comment: Sorry still the disorder, I wanted to ask how I can adapt your code solution on this page: http://chilp.it/23911c  I click `hhamilton` and I get the content. But i want this only if i click hhamilton, not the text inside the spoiler. How do I place the code? I tried but I created some conflict and the spoilers did not display correctly. Can u help me please?

Comment: I suspect that some rules that applied to some nested item (ie `.OS > .details {...}`) isn't being applied. i looked at the code in the website you linked and it is not formatted nicely at all. I would go through and tab/ format it so you can see whats going on, and then try to figure out your problems from there. firebug is an excellent tool: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Please look my short video http://chilp.it/826fe9 and download the local file for testing code http://chilp.it/2a65f6